# Density of polynomials in space $E$

Tags: functional-analysis, polynomials

Consider space $E$ - linear space $C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R})$ equipped with the system of seminorms
$$
p_{N,n}(f):= \max{|f^{(k)}(t)|: k = 0,1,…,n, t∈[−N,N]};\\
n = 0,1,2,…; N =1,2,…  
$$
where $f^{(k)}$ is a k-th derivative of function $f$.

The topology in such spaces is given by standard balls of the form:
$$
U_{ε,p_{α_1},p_{α_2},...,p_{α_n}}(x_0) = {x ∈ X : ∀ i = 1,2,...,n \quad p_{α_i}(x_0 −x) < ε} 
$$
where $p_{α_i}, ∀ i = 1,2,...,n $ are seminorms

it is necessary to prove that the set of all polynomials is dense in $E$.

One of the attempts was use in some way that continuous functions of compact support are dense and that by Stone-Weirstrass theorem, so those functions can be approximated uniformly on compact sets by polynomials. But I have troubles to make that work as there is no idea what to do about derivatives.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: For each $N,n,f,\epsilon$, take a polynomial such that $\sup_{t\in [-N,N]}|p(t)-f^{(n)}(t)|<\epsilon$. Then integrate $p$ $n$-times, choosing the right integration constants it will approximate $f$ in the $\rho_{N,n}$ norm. That's it, every open ball around $f$ contains some polynomial, so polynomials are dense.

Comment: @reuns according to definition of  topology, don’t we need to take 1 polynomial $p$ and check that given polynomial and its  derivatives approximates function $f$ and derivatives of that function?

Comment: Every open contains some polynomial. This is what it means that polynomials are dense.

Comment: @reuns I mean isn't it necessary to present one polynomial $p$ and then check that the inequalities $|p_{N,n}(p - f) |< \epsilon$, $|p_{N,n}(p' - f') |< \epsilon$, $|p_{N,n}(p'' - f'') |< \epsilon$, ..., $|p_{N,n}(p^{(k)} - f^{(k)}) |< \epsilon$ holds?

Comment: Your topology is generated by the $p_{N,n},\epsilon$ balls, no need to consider multiple $p_{N_i,n_i},\epsilon_i$ as the $p_{\max N_i, \max n_i},\min \epsilon_i$ ball is contained in it. Anyway my comment gives a way to approximate $f$ and finitely many of its derivatives in multiple seminorms at once.

Comment: @reuns Could you write your thoughts as an answer for the question